# How to move camera forward along horizontal with ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a three.js program, where when I press the "w" key it moves the camera forward.

```
if (keys.indexOf(playerControls["forward"]) != -1) {
    camera.translateZ(-0.1);
}
```

However, I want the camera to not move vertically at all, but just horizontally (x and z axes move when "w" is pressed, but y axis is ignored). How would I be able to do this? (without a bunch of trig)

Comment: You might want to take a look at this example: https://codepen.io/adelriosantiago/pen/mdBwYad?editors=1010, it is a FPS with WASD controls where the Y axis is locked.

Comment: Are you using any specific libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `translateZ` is important to move the camera in the direction you're facing, but you can easily fix the Y position by correcting it after each movement:

```js
const camHeight = 5;

if (keys.indexOf(playerControls["forward"]) != -1) {
    camera.translateZ(-0.1);
    camera.position.y = camHeight;
}
```